# QuerySet Optimisations in Django

Tags: django, django-orm, django-2.2

I was just wondering, I have the following two pseudo-related queries:

```
organisation = Organisation.objects.get(pk=org_id)
```

```
employees = Employee.objects.filter(organisation=organisation).filter(is_active=True)
```

Each `Employee` has a ForeignKey relationship with `Organisation`.

I was wondering if there is anything I can leverage to do the above in one Query in the native Django ORM?

Also, would:

```
employees = Employee.objects.filter(organisation__id=organisation.id).filter(is_active=True)
```

Be a quicker way to fetch `employees`?

---

For Willem's reference, `employees` is then used as:

```
# Before constructing **parameters, it is neccessary to filter out any supurfluous key, value pair that do not correspond to model attributes:

if len(request.GET.getlist('gender[]')) > 0:
    parameters['gender__in'] = request.GET.getlist('gender[]')
    employees = employees.filter(**parameters)

if len(request.GET.getlist('age_group[]')) > 0:
    parameters['age_group__in'] = request.GET.getlist('age_group[]')
    employees = employees.filter(**parameters)

results = SurveyResult.objects.filter(
    user__in=employees,
    created_date__range=date_range,
).annotate(
    date=TruncDate('created_date'),
).values(
    'survey',
    'date',
).annotate(
    score=Sum('normalized_score'),
    participants=Count('user'),
).order_by(
    'survey',
    'date',
)
```

I omitted this as it seemed like unnecessary complications to my original goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, would:
>
> ```
> employees = Employee.objects.filter(organisation__id=organisation.id).filter(is_active=True)
> ```
>
> Be a quicker way to fetch `employees`?

No, or perhaps marginally, since that is in essence what the Django ORM will do itself: it will simply obtain the primary key of the `organisation` and then make a query like the one you describe.

If you do not need the `organisation` itself, you can query with:

```
employees = Employee.objects.filter(organisation_id=org_pk, is_active=True)
```

Furthermore you can for example perform a [**`.select_related(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) on the organisation, to load the data of the `organisation` in the same query as the one of the employee, although reducing one extra query, usually does not make that much of a difference. Performance is more an issue if iut results in *N+1* queries.

We can for example "piggyback" fetching the `Organisation` details with fetching the employees, like:

```
employees = list(
    Employee.objects.select_related('organization').filter(
        organisation_id=org_pk, is_active=True
    )
)
if employees:  # at least one employee
    organization = employees[0].organization
```

But anyway, as said before the difference between one or two queries is not *that* much. It is usually more of a problem if you have *N+1* queries. It is a bit of a pitty that Django/Python does not seem to have a [*Haxl* [GitHub]](https://github.com/facebook/Haxl) equivalent, to enable fast retrieval of (remote) resources through algebraic analysis.

In case you are interested in the `Employee` servey results, you can query with:

```
results = SurveyResult.objects.filter(
    user__organization_id=org_pk,
    created_date__range=date_range,
).annotate(
    date=TruncDate('created_date'),
).values(
    'survey',
    'date',
).annotate(
    score=Sum('normalized_score'),
    participants=Count('user'),
).order_by(
    'survey',
    'date',
)
```

You can thus *omit* a separate querying of `Employee`s if you do not need these anyway.

You can furthermore add the filters to your query, like:

```
emp_filter = {}
genders = request.GET.getlist('gender[]')
if genders:
    emp_filter['user__gender__in'] = genders

age_groups = request.GET.getlist('age_group[]')
if age_groups:
    emp_filter['user__age_group__in'] = age_groups

results = SurveyResult.objects.filter(
    user__organization_id=org_pk,
    created_date__range=date_range,
    **emp_filter
).annotate(
    date=TruncDate('created_date'),
).values(
    'survey',
    'date',
).annotate(
    score=Sum('normalized_score'),
    participants=Count('user'),
).order_by(
    'survey',
    'date',
)
```

Comment: Ahhh, ok. So something like `employees = Employee.objects.select_related('organisation').filter(organisation_id=org_pk, is_active=True)` ? How would I then be able to reference the organisation instance?

Comment: You need to `Employee.objects.select_related('organization')`, then you can get organization by `employees.first.organization`

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos: if you need the blogs (?) of the `Employee`s. But if you want the organisation, it is thus `Employee.objects.select_related('organisation').filter(..)`.

Comment: Ahhh, copy and paste type. :D

Comment: Just to add to the addition you have made - isn't `.values_list()` or `.values()` preferential over `list(<QuerySet>)`?

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos: no, first of all `values_list` or `.values` does *not* create a list/dictionary. It makes a queryset that will, if evaluated, return lists/dictionaries (as elements). So in algebra that would be something like `fmap toList` on the queryset (with `fmap` the mapping of a *functor*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor). Furthermore `.values(..)` etc. are considered bad software design. Since it removes the logic you implemented in your fields/model/... It is usually a way to write certain queries that are usually better implemented with a normalized data model.

Comment: Ideal. Well, ok, from performance tests ... and I'm not sure why this is. But fetching the `organisation` first, then the `users` from the `organisation` as I have done in my question is much fasting than the `select_related()`....

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos: that is not suprising: Django has to process a larger set of data, and wrap the data into `Organization` objects. The number of queries indeed a dominant factor in a server performance. But as said, it is usually better to try to remove N+1 problems (https://scoutapm.com/blog/finding-and-fixing-n-1s-in-django-apps) than optimizing on single queries: it makes code less readable, and unless Django eventually will come up with something like the `Haxl` monad, it will not benefit much.

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos: see update how to omit querying for the `Employee`s itself.

Comment: Appreciate the addition, there's another complication for which I will add to my question! :D (I add in some extra additional filters). Which, although great, I think makes the above short cut unimplementable.

Comment: Accepted as the best answer. Also, cheeky, but would there be a way to get the "population" for the `Organisation`, i.e., `employees.count()`? Maybe in some sort of annotated Sum...

Answer (score 1):

if you have a foreign key relation between organisation and employees then you can get the employees using the [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) like this:

```
employees = Employee.objects.selected_related('organisation').filter(is_active=True)
```

OR

```
organisation = Organisation.objects.get(pk=org_id)
employees =organisation.employee_set.all() #your_employee_model_name_set.all
```

Comment: Are you sure `employee_set` will work just out of the box?

Comment: yes it should work if you have the foreign key relation between these two models

Comment: The foreign key is on the `Employee` model...does that effect anything?

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos: no it will make a filter, just like the one you did yourself. But this will be performed by the Django ORM. It will not have an impact on performance (it is not faster, nor is it slower).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Is the `organisation.eployee_set` performing another query? So the first employees is performing one query, and then the `employee_set` method is that performing another query...so two in total? Also, the commenter from your question who suggested `employees.first.organisation` ... isn't that another query. So, I've gone from two to two queries essentially?

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos: you should not use `first`, since that will indeed create another queryset, you can however materialize the query, and then the `organization`s of the `Employees` are loaded already in the *same* query. So then it is a single query.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So, using `user.organisation.some_attribute` with `select_related('organisation')`, and just fetching users will be sufficient to reduce from two queries to one?

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos: `.select_related(..)` will fetch the values through a JOIN, and thus wrap these in objects and update the references. So `.organization` is not *lazy* loaded anymore.

Comment: I have accepted this answer, as the second part of the 'OR' whereby fetching by the `organisation` first, then `employee_set` from the organisation performs a lot better on the DB layer than @WillemVanOnsem's answer for the particular scenario where the `organisation` instance is needed as well as the `users` `QuerySet`.

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos: did you *evaluate* the queryset, since a `organisation.employee_set.all()` does *not* query itself. It just makes a `QuerySet` object: it is only if you later force evaluation (by iterating, rendering, etc.) that you make the real query. Note that querysets are *lazy* :)

Comment: Ok, so the `employees` list is then used in another Query. I will add this to my answer for advise.

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos: but it is still *not* used. A `QuerySet` is not a query itself. A `QuerySet` is basically a "promise" that it will evaluate the objects when necessary. As in, querysets just keep data how to *make* a query if necessary. Only by iterating, printing, etc. you really force the queryset to make a query :) In category theory it is the difference between `a` and `IO a`, `IO a` is a "recipe" to return something of `a`, whereas `a` is the real result.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ok, that is making more sense, so the Query is run on evaluation. Without sounding like I am making excuses, none of this is explained in the Django documentation so for us mere mortals this is something that we need to have explained to us by the professionals :)

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos: it is, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy It says: "*QuerySets are lazy – the act of creating a QuerySet doesn’t involve any database activity. You can stack filters together all day long, and Django won’t actually run the query until the QuerySet is evaluated*".